# how to get the numeric position of the array using php

Tags: php, arrays, search, numbers, position

i want to get the **exact numeric position** of the value in the ***array***

array value:

```
$val = array('banana' , 'second' , 'apple');
```

when user *search* for the value **apple**

it will display

> 3

because it's the 3rd element

and when the user search for **banana**

it will display

> 1

Comment: [`array_search('apple', $val)`](http://php.net/array_search)

Comment: array_search(), but don't forget that array keys start from 0; so add 1 if you want to make it seem to start from 1

Comment: `echo array_flip($val)['banana'] + 1;` - not tested, you might want to use foreach or similar construct

Comment: @N.B.: That syntax doesn't work in PHP < 5.4 (also wouldn't `array_search` be better?).

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yes, array_search is significantly faster. As for php lower than 5.4 - well, tough luck for the ones using it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) like so:

```
$num = array_search('banana', $array) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys= array_keys($val, "apple")
```

Will return an array with the value 2 (all the indexes of the array that have the value "apple").

then you just have to get the first element of that array and add 1

```
$numericPosition = current($keys)
```

If $keys is empty, that is, "apple" doesnt exist in array, then $numericPosition === false, otherwise add 1. This ensures you can actually detect when a value doesnt exist, if you just add 1 to current($keys) any value not in the array will be at position 1.

Edit: array_search of the other answer will return only the 1st key of a given value, so it may match your needs better, just make sure you check for false before you add 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way (contrary to what other answers will suggest) than going through the array and checking. Any other solution will be a hack depending on the specific shape of your array (values or keys).

```
$search = "banana";

$index = 1;
foreach ($val as $v) {
   if ($v === $search) break;
   $index++;
}

echo "$search is number: $index ";
```

Comment: So `array_search` is a hack?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes. It does not return an index, it returns the key. IF your array happens to have keys that are equal to indexes, it will work. If it doesn't - it silently breaks.

Comment: @fdreger: `array_search` works for both numeric and associative arrays, returning the (first) key (*not* the index) in the array with the value: http://codepad.org/axzPOD4Z

Comment: @RocketHazmat: yes, the  key. That is the problem. The question was about "exact numeric position", not about "the exact key". The two values happen to correlate in many arrays. But not always.

Comment: @fdreger: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: @TomWalters: well, there are two of them - they are the ones with more points than the only true answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$word = 'banana';
$position = array_search($word, $val) + 1;
```